# Why was this question about Student Loan minimum payments deleted?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, deleted-questions

A few days ago, a moderator deleted this question:

[Student loan grievance: Is it illegal for servicer to lower my minimum monthly payment because I've been aggressively overpaying?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/93875/student-loan-grievance-is-it-illegal-for-servicer-to-lower-my-minimum-monthly-p)

The question was posted almost exactly one year ago.  This question has a score of +8.  Three good answers were posted, one of which (mine) was voted up to a score of +38.  The question was then closed by five members as "unclear," despite the fact that no one had asked the OP for any clarification in the comments or explained what they thought was unclear.

Now, a year later, a moderator has decided to manually delete this positive score question with all of its positive score answers.  Why was this done?

---

Please note: This is a quote from our ["moderator tools" help page](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools):

> **When should I delete questions?**
>
> Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be flagged and deleted.
>
> Before voting to delete, please check whether there are **any good answers**; if so, then the question should be flagged for moderator attention as a potential merge candidate. We don't like to lose great answers!
>
> Also, be cautious when deleting questions closed as **duplicates**; they can serve as a signpost, directing users to useful answers on another question.
>
> It takes **3** votes, minimum, to delete a closed question. However, the number of delete votes required scales to the number of votes on the question and all its answers.

(emphasis in original)

I tried to vote to reopen, but because the deletion was a moderator action, the system does not allow any non-moderators to vote to reopen.

---

My personal opinion:  The question was clear, and three users, including myself, understood it well enough to write a well-received answer.  This question should have been reopened, not deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question was closed by 5 regular (non-mod) members. Closed questions can be edited to fix whatever reason prompted the close. 
This question was closed over 10 months ago, with no such edit, and didn’t appear to be fixable.

I asked in a mod chat area, how other stacks handle this, and consensus was that these questions should be deleted. Why do you feel a closed question should remain indefinitely?

We’ve already had the meta discussion that votes don’t always reflect a good question or answer, and the CMs have written how an unclear or off topic question that somehow hits HNQ can quickly gain votes. But it should still be closed, and if not fixable, deleted.

The same day the question was posted, and the votes to close appeared, the comment also was posted -

> I voted to close this question as unclear what you're asking. I have
>   no idea what it is you're upset about or what the lender is doing or
>   not doing in response to whatever it is you think you're doing or how
>   anything written in your question could be construed as unethical
>   and/or illegal. What are the terms of the loan? What is due? What are
>   you paying? What are they doing? Did you purposely leave all of the
>   relevant details out of the question?

At the time, I thought to myself - this question will either get a good edit or a close with no help from mods. That's good, in general I think having my name added to fewer closed questions is better. The OP made no effort to edit those details quid had asked for. The question, although closed, remained available to edit, but also to show up as a 'related question' when on the site. That prompted me to talk to other stack's mods.

In general, I encourage members to let an OP return to address issues before closing a question, my own thought is that people should be given 24+ hours for a return visit. Once they've either edited or commented they won't, a close is fair.

I'd ask you a question in return - If 5 members close a question, but it remains visible, and it goes unedited/improved, what would be your criteria for deletion? I personally find it annoying to see closed questions on 'related'. They remain a reminder that something needs fixing.

Note - there are 2 Meta questions with great answers, which confirm my approach was sound -

[When should I vote to delete a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58842/when-should-i-vote-to-delete-a-question)

[How long should I wait before deleting a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138686/how-long-should-i-wait-before-deleting-a-closed-question)

Comment: There was nothing to fix. The question was closed as “unclear,” but there was no comment from anyone on what was unclear. Judging by the answers and the upvotes, many users apparently thought the question was clear, myself included.

Comment: This was not an off-topic question, so the argument that off-topic questions should be deleted does not apply here. However, I do think that, in general, closed questions with good answers should indeed remain undeleted. I spend a lot of my time writing answers on this site, and I do take it personally when my posts get deleted for no good reason. I don’t answer off-topic questions; when I answer a question, I believe it to be on-topic.

Comment: @BenMiller - I edited my answer for more details.

Comment: Thanks for posting that comment. I cannot see deleted comments. I believe that the answers to all the questions in that comment are irrelevant details. The question is answerable without knowing any of those details. I’m curious why the comment was deleted. Presumably, the comment was deleted when it was realized that the details requested are irrelevant for a good answer.

Comment: You asked for my personal criteria for deletion. First, I will acknowledge that my criteria for closure is higher than some. I don’t like seeing questions closed. If it is in the ballpark for being on-topic, I’d like to see them stay open. Often, those are the most interesting and fun questions to answer. Only if a question is nowhere near on-topic or breaks one of our explicit “off-topic” rules will I vote to close as off-topic. (Cont.)

Comment: I’ve noticed that many people tend to vote to close questions if they don’t like the OP’s attitude or they think that the OP has a mistaken view on something. I prefer in those cases to write a clever answer. When an OP takes the time to write a question, even if they are mistaken about something, an answer is what they need. Closing the question does not educate them. It only validates their mistaken view that the world is against them. (Cont.)

Comment: Now, to your question about deletion: I would only vote to delete closed questions that actively harm the site or the reader. An example: let’s say someone asked a question about the proper care of their new puppy. It might attract a few up votes from some puppy lovers, and a puppy person wanting to be helpful might even post a good answer before all the close votes come in. That question should be deleted, because having such a blatantly off-topic question remain confuses the reader and brings people here to our site from Google for the wrong reasons. (Cont.)

Comment: Another example might indeed be an “unclear” question. Let’s say that someone posted a vague question that is missing any of the necessary details for an answer. We leave it open for the OP to fix, but a user posts an answer before it gets eventually closed as “unclear.” Unfortunately, the answerer made too many assumptions, did not spell these assumptions out in his answer. Furthermore, the answer is completely wrong if you take other assumptions. This question-and-answer combo could harm the reader, giving them a false answer. I would carefully consider deletion in this case. (Cont.)

Comment: That scenario is not what we have here. This question is answerable as-is. The extra details requested in the deleted comment are not needed for the answer to the question. I can only guess that some of the “unclear” close votes were because originally it was asking a legal question without specifying a jurisdiction, but Chris correctly edited the question adding a country tag, noticing that the OP had asked other U.S.-specific questions.

Comment: There is discussion among CMs regarding the nature of closed questions. The general view is that a closed question is in a sort of limbo for a short while. Such questions should either be edited with the goal of being reopened, but not left as closed. If not reopened, they are candidates for closure, and in fact the system routinely deletes certain questions that have been left closed for a time.

Comment: As a concrete, linear thinker, I am struggling between the two very distinct issues you wish to address here. Do you feel the question should have remained open? Fair enough, I did not vote to close it, five other members did. That was nearly a year ago and I am inclined to say that ship has sailed. I don’t recall any discussion at the time arguing to re-open it as you’ve done with other questions you felt were closed  incorrectly.

Comment: The question that’s raised for me, is about leaving closed questions on the site. If you feel there is value in that and that we should not do what other stacks do, we should isolate that question for meta discussion.

Comment: Yes, and yes. I do indeed feel that this question should have been reopened, and I voted to reopen before you deleted it. And yes, there is often value in leaving closed questions on the site, especially on this site where good questions get closed occasionally.

Comment: I do not open a meta question for *every* question I think is closed unfairly; I pick my battles. :) But rest assured, if I answer a question, it means that I feel very strongly that the question should remain open, and am happy to argue that point if asked. Let me ask you: Do you think this question is unclear? What about the question do you not understand?

Comment: I see. But again, deleted over 10 months later. I can promise then it would not be my practice to delete a question that is still having active discussion or current votes to re-open. Long ago, consensus was to leave it closed.

Comment: I believe there *was* an active vote-to-reopen at the time you deleted the question. :)

Comment: I see questions that are closed that should remain open all the time. It does bother me, but I take solace in the fact that at least the good answers that got posted before the closure will remain and continue to help people, and that someday five users will gather together and rectify the wrong. Deleting well-received, valid questions with good answers solely because a few users didn’t like the question is not necessary or appropriate. Do you think this question is unclear? Do you think leaving this question on the site harms the site or the reader?

Comment: The system will not automatically delete any closed question with even a single positive-score answer.

Comment: The reasons for closing are too limiting. Unclear? Maybe not. I saw no value in the question, it felt more like a rant to me. "In the mind of the lender"? I can't read minds, not yours, not my wife's. The bank? "They're aggravated" Huh? Do they refuse the extra money above the minimum? And the Op's "lolz at the amount of questions in response to my question... Think about what they are doing: they are lowering my monthly minimum, in the hopes that I stay in debt longer. Period." Ok. Just pay what you were. It felt like he came to vent.

Comment: I understand, but I don’t like to close and delete questions solely because of attitude. Instead, I like to defuse the situation by writing a logical, reasonable answer. That is what best helps the OP and future readers that have the same concerns. If this OP has this misunderstanding, you know there are others that have the same view. Our answers can show them where they are incorrect with their thinking.

Comment: I don't want to go around in a circle, but, I did not vote to close. I just figured that 5 members were reading my mind....

Comment: I understand that you didn’t vote to close, but you did delete.Either you think the question should have been closed or not.A moderator should not, in my opinion, mindlessly delete closed questions just because they are closed. There are automatic processes in place to clean things like that up. If you think the question should remain closed, so be it. I don’t agree, but we don’t have to agree on everything. :) And even if it remains closed, I don’t think closed questions should be automatically deleted for no reason, either by the system or by a moderator mindlessly enforcing a supposed rule.

Comment: Well, I hope not (the mindless sentiment). Even if misguided, there was much thought that went into the delete. I am wondering - in exchange for a reopen, would you agree to spend (less than 1/10 the time put here today) time and edit the question to remove the charged emotion that I take offense to? In effect, changing it to what I’d consider a decent question that your answer will still apply to? (Later, I am on iPhone now, feeding my 91 yr old MIL. Getting old sux)

Comment: I’m sorry, I didn’t mean “mindless” as an insult. I apologize for the poor choice of words. What I meant was that you seemed to argue that you were simply enforcing a “rule” that mods on other sites told you to follow, perhaps without thinking about whether or not it was appropriate here.

Comment: No offense taken! Thus my kind offer. And suggestion that over time, we might agree to offer incentive to perform the edits that can move closed questions to ‘open’ status.

Comment: Of course, I would be happy to edit if that is what it will take to undelete and even perhaps reopen.  I would have edited the question a year ago if I had a clue why users were voting to close.  Unfortunately, deletion by a moderator is sort of a nuclear option that ends all debate.  While in that state, I can't edit, comment, or vote to undelete or reopen, and it can only be unlocked by another mod action.  Meta is my only option.  If it had been left undeleted, I can vote to reopen and post a comment, everyone else is free to ignore me, and life goes on.  :)

Comment: It's reopened. I'll trust you to edit.

Comment: Thank you. I will make an attempt at editing it this soon.

Comment: @BenMiller I've done some editing, feel free to make any further changes you think would help.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam Your edit looks good to me.  Thanks!

Comment: @BenMiller - can I delete this comment mess? Is there any bit that should be edited into our actual Q or A?

Comment: An anecdote from my school - I've started to use the word "mindful" in the context of slowing down and paying attention to one's math problems. One student (no flies on her) said to me "My day used to say that my mistakes were because I mindlessly rushed thru my work. I love how you turned the same word around to encourage students to do better."  Off to proctor an SAT exam, where I get to watch how students use their calculator for adding 2+2.